# How does p5.js make function setup() work like this?

Tags: function, p5.js

In p5.js, to call the *setup* function you simply write:

```
function setup() {

}
```

How did they make it so you call `function` and then the name, instead of just saying the following?

```
setup();
```

Comment: The first code  snippet is not a function call, but a function declaration. [`setup()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/setup) is called by the p5.js framework, but you don't "see" this call in your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use p5.js we don't call the `setup` function. We define a `setup` function that code inside of p5.js calls.

In the case where we have code that looks like this:

```
<script src="../p5/lib/p5.js"></script>
<script>
  function setup() {
    background(100, 0, 100);
  }
</script>
```

Our `setup` function is added to the global *window* object and can be called by code inside of p5.js. If we were running in instance mode, our `setup` function would not be added directly to the window object, but p5.js would still be able to find it and call it.

For simplicity, let's focus on the case as above where we have written `setup` and it is attached to the window object.

Looking at the p5.js source code, we see a function called `_setup` and in that function this code:

```
if (typeof context.setup === 'function') {
  context.setup();
}
```

This is where our `setup` gets called. If we add this alert:

```
if (typeof context.setup === 'function') {
  if (context === window)alert("context is window");
    context.setup();
}
```

we can verify that the context object is indeed the *window* object and `_setup` is calling the `setup` function that we created in our code.

Comment: Thanks so much, I was confused how they did it.

Comment: There is a lot that can be learned by looking at the p5.js source code and even more by adding experimental code.